# Efficient Generation of Unique Fixed Length Codes

Tags: python, hash, sha1

I am creating a program that generates unique codes that each consist of 10 alphanumeric characters but I was wondering if there is an efficient algorithm in order to do so. I am using the `random.choice` function to determine these codes if they do not already exist in a list, but this is very inefficient.

I have looked into hashing by indices with SHA1 such no collisions are made. However, the generated hash codes are not of a fixed length of ten characters. How can I do the same to produce results of 10 characters? Please do not suggest slicing. That would increase chances of collision.

Comment: How many codes do you need? And do you know in advance how many you need?

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, the client will enter the number of codes to be generated.

Comment: Why "no"? Then you do have the number before you generate them, no?

Comment: What are you talking about? The user specifies how many unique codes should be made.

Comment: But that sounds like you do know the number in advance, so I don't understand why you replied "no" to that. You should probably specify how unique they need to be (like from just unique inside one request to unique globally among all requests on all installations of your program anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/uuid.html) module which solves that problem exactly.
If you insist on having fixed length codes, I would hash the output of uuid (with eg sha1) and select the first `n` bytes.

Comment: Would selecting the first `n` bytes increase chances of collision?

Comment: Yes, because you have less possibilities in n bytes. Hashing would reduce the probability, compared to selecting the first few bytes of the uuid.

Comment: It would be even better to pick the first few bytes of each field, but slightly trckier and less general.

Comment: So could you provide a foolproof option with sample code to guide me?

Comment: So could you clarify and solidify the concept with some code?